# Share link and image on facebook

Tags: android, facebook, image, hyperlink, share

I have this simple problem made complicated because of FB. I try to share from android a link and image using facebook sdk.
Did anyone played with ShareOpenGraphObject, ShareOpenGraphAction and ShareOpenGraphContent before, facebook documentation just sucks, no examples at all. I am waiting for examples.

Thanks

Comment: Personally I have not. I am sure a lot of people are willing to help, but you have to show some code.

Comment: I am pretty sure FB documentation is good enough. If you need help you should post some code what you have tried so far.

Comment: let s post some code then:

Answer (score 2):

let s post some code then:

```
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "books.book")
            .putString("og:title", "A Game of Thrones")
            .putString("og:description", "In the frozen wastes to the north of Winterfell, sinister and supernatural forces are mustering.")
            .putString("books:isbn", "0-553-57340-3")
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("books.reads")
            .putObject("book", object)
            .putPhoto("image", photo)
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("book")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

    shareDialog.show(this, content);
```

idea is that i don t want to use a book, i just want so share a image a link and a message...how the f i do that? facebook sdk sucks

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple, You can find many examples as well as in Facebook SDK you can find sample for the same...

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();           
postParams.putString("link", url);
postParams.putString("picture", imgUrl);

    Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, 
                    HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
```

Comment: not simple at all, fb docs sucks, and i want to create a content and display it so users can edit. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think by using facebook sdk 4.0, you can share contents via share api.

eg:

```
public void share()
{
ShareLinkContent content=new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
.setContentTitle("Your Title")
.setContentUrl(Uri.parse("website link"))
.setImageUrl(Uri.parse("Image url"))
.build();

ShareApi.share(content, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>(){
@Override
public void onSuccess(Result result){

}
@Override
public void onCancel(){

}
@Override
public void onError(FacebookException error){

}
});
}
```

Comment: could be a solution, but it isnt :D, i have to share a local picture, not one from a link

Comment: You can share local images using sharePhoto class, which is specified in facebook sdk document.

Comment: i know i can use sharePhoto, but also i need to attach a link and a comment to the Photo...do u know how can i do that?

Comment: SharePhotoContent Class provide an option to  add sharephoto and ContentUrl. But, i am not sure it is worked.

Comment: not working, content url only works to upload a pic from a url, nothing more

Answer (score 0):

For sharing link and image , **ShareDialog**
Provides functionality to share content via the Facebook Share Dialog and

**ShareLinkContent**
Describes link content to be shared.

is one method without the Open Graph method.

Snippet is like

```
private ShareDialog shareDialog;
private boolean canPresentShareDialogWith;

shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

canPresentShareDialogWith = ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class);


ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().setContentTitle("Shared from " + "<APP NAME>")
                            .setContentDescription(
                                    "Question:" + data.getQuestion() + "\n"
                            // + "Asked by : "
                            // + data.getName() + "\n"
                            )
                            .setContentUrl(
                                    Uri.parse("<Website url>"))
                            .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(data.getPicUploadPath()))
                            .build();

                    if (canPresentShareDialogWith) {
                        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
                    } else if (profile != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
                        ShareApi.share(linkContent, shareCallback);
                    }


private FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> shareCallback = new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d("HelloFacebook", "Canceled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        Log.d("HelloFacebook", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
        String title = getString(R.string.error);
        String alertMessage = error.getMessage();
        showResult(title, alertMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
        Log.d("HelloFacebook", "Success!");
        if (result.getPostId() != null) {
            String title = getString(R.string.success);
            String id = result.getPostId();
            String alertMessage = getString(
                    R.string.successfully_posted_post, id);
            showResult(title, alertMessage);
        }
    }

    private void showResult(String title, String alertMessage) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(NewsfeedMain.this).setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(alertMessage)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null).show();
    }
};
```

The method here is sharing a link with the respective web url to load , when clicked from FB feed and the image shared is via a **link** by the native facebook android app or fallback to sdk share dialog is no facebook app is persent.